# JPA join on own table to get both tables columns

Tags: java, jpa, join

Consider following simplified situation.  You got a table with a person that has a pickup record and delivery record.  This in a database you cannot change since it's a legacy database not under your control.

```
ID    PERSON    TYPE        TIME
1     PersonA   PICKUP      07:00
2     PersonA   DELIVERY    08:00
```

The result I want from my query is the following

```
PersonA PICKUP 07:00 DELIVERY 08:00
```

I could do this in SQL by doing

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.person p1.type, p1.time, p2.type, p2.time
FROM Orders p1
INNER JOIN Orders p2
   ON p1.person = p2.person
   AND p2.type = 'DELIVERY'
WHERE p1.type = 'PICKUP'
```

However since the application is build with JPA and you want abstraction for your testing, cause you have no idea what the schema in the database eventually will be.  I like this in a JPA query, but sofar I don't see how to do this.  I was thinking using a @JoinColumn to it's own classe but again I can't change the database and wouldn't that create a new column in the db or a mapping table.  If there really is no solution I'll have to use native query , however I really like to avoid it.  The JPA implementation we are using is hibernate shipped by the spring framework.

Something I was thinking of was maybe using the type column as discriminator and create two Entity classes and somehow join them together.